# Labeling future object in threading

Tags: java, multithreading, future, executorservice

I have a for loop in which i make call to db to get some values of a student. Now for loop takes a lot of time. So thought to replace that with executor service with future objects. At the start of function i made calls to db using `executor.submit()` method.
I am just not sure how to find the future objects returned is for that particular student which i can use for further steps. Please find below the code

Function below is getting called from a for loop which overall takes lot of time since getting called by each Student:

```
public void getDbDetails(String student){
       //calling db
       if(dbDetails.studentName = "XYZ"){
          //function based on student ID
       }
}
```

Using Executor Framework:

```
public void getStudentData(List<String> students){
   final List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String student: students){
            Future<?> future = executor.submit(() ->{
                //db call
            });
            futures.add(future);
        }
}

public void getDbDetails(String student){
//In this case how would i know whether future has returned details for this particular student??
if(dbDetails.studentName = "XYZ"){
              //function based on student ID
           }
}
```

Is it possible to use `future.get()` and create a map based on the studentId from future object and then use that map in function **getDbDetails()** to fetch particular student information and if future has not returned anything by that time then use `Thread.wait();`? Is this approach right or anything else can be used as optimum solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your return value on your task is `void`. Instead you should be defining a `Callable` that returns a value.

A rough draft of some untested code:

```java
public class StudentNameLookup implements Callable < String >
{
    private String studentId ;
    
    public StudentNameLookup ( String studentId ) 
    {
        this.studentId = studentId ;
    }
    
    public String call()
    {
        String studentName ;
        // … DB call, passing `this.studentId`, returning a value stored in `studentName` local var. 
        return studentName ;
    }
}
```

In Java 16+ we could use a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) for brevity.

```java
public record StudentNameLookup ( String studentId ) implements Callable < String >
{
    public String call()
    {
        String studentName ;
        // … DB call, passing `this.studentId`, returning a value stored in `studentName` local var. 
        return studentName ;
    }
}
```

As a matter of taste, I would build up a list of tasks.

```
List < Callable < String > > tasks = new ArrayList<>();
for( String studentId : studentIds )
{
    Callable < String > task = new StudentNameLookup( studentId ) ;
    tasks.add( task ) ;
}
```

[Submit all the tasks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) to an executor service. You get back a list of futures.

The parameterized type (angle brackets) of your futures will be the type of that return value you declared on your `Callable`.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors. … ;
List < Future < String > > futures = es.invokeAll( tasks ) ;
```

Then do the usual executor service work. Do a shutdown, await termination. After that, you know all the submitted tasks have been processed.

Loop your list of futures. Test each future to see if it succeeded, then retrieve its result.

```
String studentName = future.get() ;
```

Read Javadoc and search Stack Overflow for boilerplate.

If you want to return the student id along with the retrieved student name, change your return type. Instead of returning a mere `String`, return an object of a type you invent, a type that include both id and name.

```
public record Student ( String id , String name ) {}
```

Change the parameterized types (angle brackets) seen in code above from `< String >` to `< Student >`.